# Подскажите название слайдера

Tags: javascript, jquery, слайдер

[image]

Как называется показанная на картинке галерея? Или может есть варианты, которые можно подогнать под себя. Обязательным является при наведении мыши на картинку всплывающие кнопки поделиться и приблизить (возможности добавлять кнопки самому будет достаточно).